# deploy rpm file into nexus repo in maven project

Tags: java, maven, rpm-maven-plugin

i created a rpm package using `rpm-maven-plugin`, and now I try to deploy it into my nexus with another maven plugin.

I have tried to do it with `deploy-maven-plugin`

version 2.8.2. but it failed with error message that it couldnt push metadata files into the nexus. I omly want to push the rpm package without any meta data, how can i do it?

Comment: Always add the error message you get, not your own summary of them